# Is it possible to update Hangfire WorkerCount for a specific job?

Tags: c#, .net, hangfire

I am working in a `.NET Framework` application with Hangfire that runs background jobs.

There is one specific job that I want to be run with fewer workers in parallel.

Therefore, I can write this code:

```cs
var options = new BackgroundJobServerOptions
{
    WorkerCount = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2 // Default is ProcessorCount * 5
};

app.UseHangfireServer(options);
```

The problem with this code is that it is a global change and will be applied to all the background jobs while I want to apply it only to a specific background job. It is possible?

Comment: Are you test DisableConcurrentExecution attribute ?

Comment: @MiladDastanZand No. Why?

Comment: I think this may be helpful : https://github.com/alastairtree/Hangfire.MaximumConcurrentExecutions

Comment: @mike Thanks! It seems to be what I am searching for. I see the example is with BackgroundJob.Enqueue() function. Is it works also for RecurringJob?

Comment: I think this extension would be suitable in this case : https://github.com/LabelZhou/Hangfire.Dashboard.RecurringJobExtensions

Comment: @mike Did you mean https://github.com/icsharp/Hangfire.RecurringJobExtensions/ ?